# How to get category value in slot (Vuetify calendar)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am having trouble figuring out how to have hover functionality in categories view of Vuetify calendar in the body part (slot `day-body`). Now when I implement the hover functionality, the whole row has the hover, but I am hovering over one category only. Everything else such as the week, day and 4-day is working properly because I can individually get `date`, `week` and `timeToY` from the `day-body` slot.

```html
<template v-slot:day-body="{ date, timeToY }">
  <div :class="{ hover: isHover && date === hoverDate }"
       :style="{ top: `${timeToY(hoverY)}px` }">
     <p class="mt-2 ml-2">{{ hoverY }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is the HTML that I am using and these two events `@mousemove:time="hoverToSeeTime"` and `@mouseleave:time="removeHover"`.  In the mousemove handler I assign `isHover`, `hoverDate` and `hoverY`. But I can't grasp how to make individual category tiles hoverable **because `day-body` slot does not have the category key. Am I missing anything?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `day-body` does indeed have the `category` key.  Can you post a reproduction of the problem on https://codepen.io or https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: Sure, just implemented in codepen [here](https://codepen.io/brianencoder/pen/oNzxoPW). Please hover over calendar body to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@mousemove:time-category` and `@mouseleave:time-category` instead and `category` will be available in the event handler.  Then you can set a `hoverCategory` along with the other `hover` properties:

```js
hoverToSeeTime({ date, time, category }) {
   ...
   this.hoverCategory = category;
   ...
}
```

`category` is available in the slot props:

```html
<template v-slot:day-body="{ date, week, timeToY, category }">
```

So you can compare the two in the slot template.  Adjust that template to use a `v-if` on the div instead of a conditional class:

```html
<template v-slot:day-body="{ date, week, timeToY, category }">
   <div v-if="category == hoverCategory && date === hoverDate"
       class="hover" :style="{ top: `${timeToY(hoverY)}px` }"
   >
      <p class="mt-2 ml-2">{{ hoverY }}</p>
   </div>
</template>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/sh0ber/pen/PoGNQKz) is an updated codepen